# NPM Install Fails with 404 for 'react-rerror-bounday' Package

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I'm working on a React project, and I'm facing issues when running npm install. I keep getting a 404 error for the package 'react-rerror-bounday', which I suspect is a typo. Here is the relevant part of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  // ... other dependencies
  "react-rerror-bounday": "^4.0.4"
}
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-rerror-bounday - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'react-rerror-bounday@^4.0.4' is not in this registry.
```

[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I resolve it?

Successfull NPM Install

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I cloned the package repo, and when i installed, i found this.